# TypeError: fontkit.create is not a function => problem faced while I was adopting customfont to my pdf using pdf-lib

Tags: javascript, typescript, pdf, fonts

I am currently modifying pdf files using javascript libraries and node.
This is my code and I cannot solve thr problem of *TypeError: fontkit.create is not a function*

This is my code.

```
const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(existingPdfBytes);
pdfDoc.registerFontkit(fontkit);
const fontUrl =
      'https://storage.googleapis.com/filepath/KaushanScript-Regular.ttf';
    const fontBytes = await fetch(fontUrl).then((res) => res.arrayBuffer());
    pdfDoc.registerFontkit(fontBytes);
const customFont = await pdfDoc.embedFont(fontBytes);
```

While embedding the font, the problem mentioned above occurs.

This is the built-in method of CustomFontSubsetEmbedder.ts

```
enter code herestatic async for(
fontkit: Fontkit,
fontData: Uint8Array,
customFontName?: string,
fontFeatures?: TypeFeatures,) {
const font = await fontkit.create(fontData);
return new CustomFontSubsetEmbedder(
  font,
  fontData,
  customFontName,
  fontFeatures,
);}
```

The problem is occuring in the built-in section where I can't control.

My @pdf-lib/fontkit version is 1.1.1
("@pdf-lib/fontkit": "^1.1.1" on my package.json)

I've been trying various ways to fix this but I couldn't.